# Bash script fails when run via script

Tags: bash

These commands, when run as a script, fails with error:

> /etc/nginx/.htpasswd: No such file or directory

```
sudo touch /etc/nginx/.htpasswd
hash="$(echo -n "$MD5Password" | md5sum )"
echo "${ApplicationUserName}:$hash" >> /etc/nginx/.htpasswd
```

However, when I execute them one at a time manually they work just fine.

Complete code:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
yum -y update
yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
yum install httpd-tools -y
echo
/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init --verbose --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource EC2Instance --region ${AWS::Region}
/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource EC2Instance --region ${AWS::Region}
sudo touch /etc/nginx/.htpasswd
hash="$(echo -n "$MD5Password" | md5sum )"
echo "${ApplicationUserName}:$hash" >> /etc/nginx/.htpasswd
```

This is part of user data I am passing in an AWS Cloudformation template.

What am I missing here?

Comment: you shouldn't need to use `sudo` when running user data (see [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-shell-scripts)). What sort of output do you see in `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`?

Comment: @tkwargs /etc/nginx/.htpasswd: No such file or directory

Comment: I suspect your script file has CRLF line breaks, use `dos2unix` to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The error message occurs because the `/etc/nginx` directory doesn't exist. Change it to:

```
mkdir -p /etc/nginx
touch /etc/nginx/.htpasswd
```

And it should be fine.

As noted in comments, the sudo isn't required or recommended there, so I removed it.

> However, when I execute them one at a time manually they work just fine.

That's not possible. Something else must be creating the `/etc/nginx` directory later in your script or build process, but prior to you trying those commands manually. Maybe you install the `nginx` rpm later perhaps?

Comment: Did this answer your question @shabbirbata ?